# How to modify the -webkit-scrollbar styles in a QWebView

Tags: c++, qt, qwebview, qwebkit

Webkit provides special css properties for styling scrollbars, for example:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color:white;
}
```

Normally I'd put these inside a `<style>` tag inside `<head>`, but unfortunately QWebElement doesn't seem to be able to modify anything inside `<head>`. I can use the `setHtml()` function to specify initial styling, but not modify it later. Is there an alternative way to  apply CSS styles to the scrollbars in a QWebFrame?

Comment: QWebElement doesn't seem to be able to manipulate scoped `<style>` tags in the `<body>` section either. It does anything I want until I change the name of the tag to `style`.

Comment: Hi! My answer solve your problem? If so check as "correct", if not tell me what is missing.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct for the question I asked, but as I mentioned, I need to generate the styles dynamically at runtime because I don't know in advance what colour scrollbar will be required. If I hard-coded every possible colour scheme in the resource file then it would be a very big resource file.

Comment: I added a example for load `QString` like CSS file, try use, if it not work for you, please, uncheck my answer and provide an example of how you did with the "setHTML" (I know it did not work, just to understand how to get the data). I hope I can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is possible using [`QWebSettings::setUserStyleSheetUrl`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwebsettings.html#setUserStyleSheetUrl), see example:

```
const QString path = PATH_OF_CSS_FILE;
QWebSettings *settings = QWebSettings::globalSettings();
settings->setUserStyleSheetUrl(QUrl(path));
```

### Example

If dynamic CSS is a string, you can create a method and use [`QTemporaryFile`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/qtemporaryfile.html), like this:

```
void MainWindow::setStyle(const QString data)
{
    QTemporaryFile file;
    if (file.open()) {
        const QString path = file.fileName();

        QWebSettings *settings = QWebSettings::globalSettings();
        settings->setUserStyleSheetUrl(QUrl(path));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
setStyle("::-webkit-scrollbar-track { background-color:white;}")
```

If needs load dynamic file, you can create an alternative method like this:

```
void MainWindow::setStyle(const QUrl url)
{
    QWebSettings *settings = QWebSettings::globalSettings();
    settings->setUserStyleSheetUrl(url);
}
```

### Using QRC

Is part of the answer is just a tip for other implementations;

You can use resources ([QRC](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/resources.html)) in your project for put default stylesheet for all `QWebView`s, see example:

- Click right button in your project > Add New ... > Qt > Qt Resource File > Put name "resources.qrc"
- Click right button in "resources.qrc" > Open in Editor
- Put a CSS file with name scrollbar.css (css file must be in the same folder as your project).

Put this in your "main.cpp":

```
#include <QWebSettings>
#include <QUrl>

...

const QString path = "qrc:/scrollbar.css";
QWebSettings *settings = QWebSettings::globalSettings();
settings->setUserStyleSheetUrl(QUrl(path));
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to be able to modify the scrollbar styling dynamically at runtime, and there is no way of knowing in advance what color scheme the user will request. Therefore hard-coding the colors in a resource file doesn't help so much?